# Spark sql insert overwrite directory options

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Insert overwrite directory syntax to write a dataframe to s3.

Below works fine:

```
spark.sql(s"""INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://test/test1' USING PARQUET SELECT * FROM df""")
```

But I am not able to figure out how to specify a partition column while writing. I appreciate any help on this.

Reference page: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-overwrite-directory.md

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: you have to create a table if you want to overwrite the partitions https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/insert.html#dynamic-partition-inserts